# Using classes and methods defined in another module from within a django view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a module that handles upload of CSV's
Within the module,I have a file called twzworkscsvreader.py that contains classes and functions that check if the file uploaded is a csv file by looking at the header(defined) and throws errors if the file didn't upload successfully.presently, i can see the errors from the console.
I want to add a functionality within my view that returns this errors to the page in the browser instead of just printing them to the console.
here is the twzworkscsvreader.py part that handles this errors

```
import logging
import csv
import time
import warnings
import datetime
import dateutil.parser as dparser
import os

class CSVFileReader:
    def __init__(self, filename, evidence, mysql, filetype):
        """ Class constructor.
        Args:
         - filename: csv file name to process
         - evidence: evidence number supplied from the command line
         - mysql:    instance of the mySQL database
         - filetype: type of the file to process
        """
        self.errorCount = 0
        self.path = filename
        self.evidence = evidence
        self.mysql = mysql
        self.dictInstance = {}
        self.filetype = filetype

        #TO DO: move this outside maybe back into function. I dont think this is right place this this.
        self.artifacts = ['AuditPolicy','App Paths','exefile open\command','cmdfile open\command','batfile open\command','htafile open\command','piffile open\command',\
                          'http open\command','browsers','Run keys','NetworkCards','Browser Helper Objects']

    def is_arbitrary_text(self,row):
        """
        Check if an TZworks CSV header is present
        Args:
            row: the row as it was read from the csv
        Returns:
            Boolean: True or False
        """
        ##TO DO CLEAN UP HOW THIS IS FORMATTED BELOW. MAYBE PULL ALL THIS INTO A SEPERATE FILE.
        if self.filetype == "jmp" and str(row) == "['source path/filename', 'source type        ', 'appid           ', 'MRU/MFU', 'stream#', 'MRU date    ', 'MRU-UTC      ', 'file mdate  ', 'mtime-UTC    ', 'file adate  ', 'atime-UTC    ', 'file cdate  ', 'ctime-UTC    ', 'tgt mdate   ', 'mtime-UTC    ', 'tgt adate   ', 'atime-UTC]   ', 'tgt cdate   ', 'ctime-UTC    ', 'ObjID cdate ', 'ctime-UTC    ', 'tgt attrib', 'inode     ', 'seq#  ', 'file size ', 'target name                                                 ', 'idlist extra info                                           ', 'vol type', 'vol serial', 'vol label', 'local path', 'common path', 'network/device info', 'extra info', 'netbios name', 'volume id', 'object id', 'mac addr']":
                return True

        elif self.filetype == "usb" and str(row) == "['device name', 'vid/pid', ' time-utc', 'install', ' time-local', \
'disk dev', ' time-utc', 'vol dev', ' time-utc', 'type', 'vid', 'pid', 'hub', 'port', \
'vendor', 'product', 'rev', 'volume guid', 'vol', 'vol name', 'users [ date/time - utc]', \
'instance id/serial #', 'Other dates defined by explicit property keys', 'Readyboost (freeform list of EMDMgmt entries) vol serial# / vol name / last modify regtimes [utc] and * = test time']":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "link" and str(row) == "['source path/filename', 'source type', 'file mdate', ' time-UTC', 'file adate', ' time-UTC', \
'file cdate', 'ctime-UTC', 'tgt mdate', ' time-UTC', 'tgt adate', ' time-UTC]', 'tgt cdate', ' time-UTC', 'ObjID cdate', ' ctime-UTC', 'tgt attrib', \
'inode', 'seq#', 'file size', 'target name', 'idlist extra info', 'vol type', 'vol serial', 'vol label', 'local path', 'common path', 'network/device info', \
'extra info', 'netbios name', 'volume id', 'object id', 'mac addr']":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "prefetch" and str(row) == "['prefetch file name                    ',' app name             ',' times ran',' last run  ', \
' time-utc    ',' mdate     ',' time-utc',' adate     ',' time-utc',' cdate     ',' time-utc',' path/appname        ',' Num Vols',' volume(s)', \
' volume serial(s)',' volume date/time(s) (utc)',' Num modules',' Module list']":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "sbag" and str(row) == "['regdate', ' reg-UTC', 'mru', 'mdate', ' time-UTC', 'adate', ' time-UTC', 'cdate', ' time-UTC', \
'type', 'bag', 'file size', 'inode', 'seq#', 'full path', 'source subkey/value name', 'user acct', 'extra metadata', 'bag registry dates related to this entry']":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "AuditPolicy" and row == "regdate, reg-UTC,policy name,type audit":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "App Paths" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,subkey,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "exefile open\command" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "cmdfile open\command" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "batfile open\command" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "htafile open\command" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "piffile open\command" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "http open\command" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "browsers" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,subkey,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "Run keys" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "NetworkCards" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,subkey,value name,value data":
            return True

        elif self.filetype == "Browser Helper Objects" and row == "reg date, reg-UTC,subkey,value name,value data":
            return True

        else:
            return False

    #TODO: Move this to its own file
    def StringToDatetime(self, datetime, dt_type):
        """Converts a string timestamp into a datetime object.

        Args:
           datetime: A string formatted as a timestamp (i.e 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000).
           dt_type:  which datetime field we are parsing. Used for logging purposes

        Returns:
           A datetime object or None if the parsing fails."""
        # Here some dates have space (like "install" and some are just empty (like "userDateTime)
        # so we need to check for both conditions
        if datetime == " " or datetime == "" or datetime == "                         ":
            self.errorCount += 1
            #TO DO: Use %s
            message = dt_type + " is missing the date at line "
            message += str(self.rowcount)
            logging.warn(message)
            return None
        else:
            try:
                datetimeobject = dparser.parse(str(datetime))
                return datetimeobject
            except:
                self.errorCount += 1
                #TO DO: Use %s
                message = dt_type + " has incorrect date at line "
                message += str(self.rowcount)
                logging.error(message)
                return None

    def readyBoostParse(self, string):
        """Parse the last field of the csv file
            Args:
              string:   string representation of the last field in the csv
            Returns:
              readyboostDict: dictionary of the items in the readyboost field

        """
        #Readyboost (freeform list of EMDMgmt entries) vol serial# / vol name / last modify regtimes [utc] and * = test time

        readyboostDict = {}
        readyboost_items = string.split(';')
        item_counter = 1
        for item in readyboost_items:
            if len(readyboost_items) > 5:
                self.errorCount += 1
                logging.error("Too many readyboost items at line " + str(self.rowcount))
            try:
                vol_sn_and_vol_name , _, last_mod_regdatetime = item.partition("[")
                vol_sn, _, vol_name = vol_sn_and_vol_name.partition("/")
                readyboostDict['volume_serial' + str(item_counter)] = vol_sn.replace('-', '')
                readyboostDict['volume_name' + str(item_counter)] = vol_name
                readyboostDict['last_modify' + str(item_counter)] = self.StringToDatetime(last_mod_regdatetime.strip("]"), "readyboost")
                item_counter += 1

            except Exception as e:
                self.errorCount += 1
                #TO DO add better error handeling and logging.
                readyboostDict['volume_serial' + str(item_counter)] = ""
                readyboostDict['volume_name' + str(item_counter)] = ""
                readyboostDict['last_modify' + str(item_counter)] = None
                item_counter += 1

        return readyboostDict

    def readAdditionalData(self):
        """ Read the data from the additional CSV file
            Args:
                None
            Return:
                None
        """
        in_header = False
        headerPassed = False
        internalHeader = False
        #Why not use the other readData?
        with open(self.path, "rb") as csvfile:
            for line in csvfile:
                line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
                if not line:
                    continue
                if internalHeader and headerPassed:
                    if line != "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ":# and not in_header:
                        if self.filetype == "AuditPolicy":
                            self.processAuditPolicyData(line)
                        if self.filetype == "App Paths":
                            self.processAppPathData(line)
                        if self.filetype == "exefile open\command":
                            self.processExeFileOpenCommand(line)
                        if self.filetype == "cmdfile open\command":
                            self.processCmdFileOpenCommand(line)
                        if self.filetype == "batfile open\command":
                            self.processBatFileOpenCommand(line)
                        if self.filetype == "htafile open\command":
                            self.processHtaFileOpenCommand(line)
                        if self.filetype == "piffile open\command":
                            self.processPifFileOpenCommand(line)
                        if self.filetype == "http open\command":
                            self.processHttpOpenCommand(line)
                        if self.filetype == "browsers":
                            self.processBrowsers(line)
                        if self.filetype == "Run keys":
                            self.processRunKeys(line)
                        if self.filetype == "NetworkCards":
                            self.processNetworkCards(line)
                        if self.filetype == "Browser Helper Objects":
                            self.processBrowserHelperObject(line)
                    else:
                        internalHeader = False
                        headerPassed = False
                        self.filetype = ""
                if line == "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ":# and not in_header:
                    if not in_header:
                        in_header = True
                    else:
                        in_header = False
                        headerPassed = True
                    continue
                #if line == "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- " and in_header:
                    #in_header = False
                    #headerPassed = True
                    #continue
                if in_header:
                    (key,value) = line.split(':')
                    value = value.strip()
                    if key == "Artifact":
                        if value not in self.artifacts:
                            print "Unknown artifact found."
                            logging.error("Unknown artifact found in file: {0:s}".format(self.path))
                            return
                        else:
                            self.filetype = value
                            continue
                    else:
                        continue
                elif headerPassed and not internalHeader:
                    if not self.is_arbitrary_text(line):
                        return False
                    else:
                         internalHeader = True

    def readData(self):
        """ Read the data from the CSV file.
            Args:
               None
            Return:
               None
        """
        try:
            import codecs
            with open(self.path, "rU") as data_initial:
                reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in data_initial), delimiter=",")

                ##oldcode
                #data_initial = open("staff.csv", "rU")
                #reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in csvfile), delimiter=",")
                #reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')


                #Row number where header exists
                rangecount = 0
                #Check if more then one header exists in file.
                header = False
                #Count number of rows. Need to test to see what happens if error on one row.
                self.rowcount = 1

                for row in reader:
                    #Check if expected header is in place and if there are no other headers in file.
                    if self.is_arbitrary_text(row) == True and header == False:
                         for _ in range(rangecount):
                             next(reader, None)
                             self.is_arbitrary_text(reader)
                         reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in data_initial), delimiter=",")
                         #Do processing for each row
                         for row in reader:
                             if self.filetype == "usb":
                                 self.processUSBData(row)
                             if self.filetype == "lnk":
                                 self.processLNKData(row)
                             if self.filetype == "prefetch":
                                 self.processPreFetchData(row)
                             if self.filetype == "sbag":
                                 self.processSBagData(row)
                             if self.filetype == "jmp":
                                 self.processJmpData(row)
                             self.rowcount += 1
                         header = True
                    else:
                        rangecount +=1

                if header == False:
                    logging.error("Did not find expected header in CSV file: " + self.path)
                    print "Did not find expected header in CSV file %s." % (self.path)


        except IOError as e:
            print "Error parsing file: %s". e.args[1]
```

can anyone write me a prototype of using this class within my view to so that it displays the errors to page? the class is defined within a module i have called mysq_db_loader and in a file called twzworkscsvreader.py

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django this package does a lot nice abstraction on top of CSV files:  https://github.com/fusionbox/django-separated